# Automate dailpad after answering a incoming call on android device

Tags: android, python-3.x

Hi I am trying to automate mobile device using python, but I am failing. . My requirement is as follows.

1. Answer an incoming call
2. Click on the dailpad/keypad

Can someone help me with the solution

This is my python code

```
import subprocess
import time

# Simulate answering an incoming call (Note: This might not work on all devices)
subprocess.call(['adb', 'shell', 'input', 'keyevent', 'KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK'])

# Wait for a few seconds to simulate user interaction
time.sleep(5)
subprocess.call(['adb', 'shell', 'input', 'keyevent', 'KEYCODE_CALL'])
print("opened keypad")
time.sleep(2)
# Simulate keypress events (e.g., pressing '1', '2', '3')
subprocess.call(['adb', 'shell', 'input', 'keyevent', 'KEYCODE_1'])
time.sleep(1)  # Add delays between keypresses as needed
subprocess.call(['adb', 'shell', 'input', 'keyevent', 'KEYCODE_2'])
time.sleep(1)
subprocess.call(['adb', 'shell', 'input', 'keyevent', 'KEYCODE_3'])

# End the call (simulating pressing the "End Call" button)
subprocess.call(['adb', 'shell', 'input', 'keyevent', 'KEYCODE_ENDCALL'])
```

Comment: If you're trying to "click on a dialpad", nothing you have there does that.  You're sending key events, that's the equivalent of having a bluetooth keyboard attacked and pressing 1, 2, 3, etc.  That might work, depending on what dialer app is installed (the dialer is not the same on all devices), but it's not clicking anything